# tail probability of max of Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I'm trying to follow an argument in C. Giraud's "**High Dimensional Statistics**" (2nd Ed, p. 11 / $\S$ 1.2.3).  The specific page is accessible via Google Books [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_High_Dimensional_Statist/YiM_EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=high%20dimensional%20statistics&pg=PR19&printsec=frontcover) but the formatting is awful.

Suppose that $\epsilon_j \sim {\cal N}(0,1), j = 1, \ldots, p$ and these are all independent.

Then $\mathbb{P}[ \max_j |\epsilon_j| \geq x] = 1 - (1 - \mathbb{P}[|\epsilon_1| > x])^p$.  I understand the steps to get the expression on the right from the one on the left.

What I don't understand is the next part, where a limit is taken (?) in $p$:

$\mathbb{P}[ \max_j |\epsilon_j| \geq x] = 1 - (1 - \mathbb{P}[|\epsilon_1| \geq x])^p \sim^{p \rightarrow \infty } p \mathbb{P}[ |\epsilon_1| \geq x]$

I guess the result is approximate but I cannot grasp the necessary steps.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of this formula is
$$P(\max_j |\epsilon_j| \ge x) = 1-(1-P(|\epsilon_1| \ge x))^p 
\underset{x \to\infty}\sim p \,P(|\epsilon_1| \ge x)$$
for each real $p>0$,
which follows because $(1-u)^p=1-(p+o(1))u$ as $u\to0$.

(The reproduction quality of the preview of the book is indeed terrible. It is also clear that $1-(1-P(|\epsilon_1| \ge x))^p 
\underset{p\to\infty}\to1$ for each real $x$.)

Comment: That is a nice fact which I did not know.  Thanks!